# how to locate the nested span element locator

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

how to locate only parent span which is containing the price value from the below Code,locator strategy doesn't matter:

```
<div class="price-box price-margin">
    <p class="old-price"></p>
    <p class="special-price">
        <span id="product-price-75254" class="price">
                              56,90 € 
             <span class="steuerstern">*</span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `//span[contains(., "56,90 €")]` ?

Comment: value of the price and id for that span is not fixed, It will change according to product selection, Needs to be Generic locator for span

Comment: `//p[@class="special-price"]/span[@class="price"]`

Comment: Which will include child span class(*), i do not want to take that into consideration, just wanted to retrive price(56,90 €) not (56,90 €)*. The locator you have provided is gives me (56,90 €)*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the selector here. But the text function.

```
//p[@class="special-price"]/span[@class="price"]
```

This will select the node, but selenium will always return the node of the child nodes also. What you are looking for is the node text in this case. This can only be done using JavaScript. Since you didn't mention a language I am going to assume python

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="special-price"]/span[@class="price"]')

price = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent.trim();", elem)

print(price)
56,90 €
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selector you can go like this:

```
".price-box span.price"
```

Result:

```
56,90 €
```

Answer (score 0):

To test the xpath correctness in Chrome you can use

```
//span[@class="price"]/text()
```

Since you didn't mention the language you use , here is an example in nightwatchjs with selenium by using .getText()

.getText() is returning an object, the actual text is the value of callback.

```
var thetext='';
.getText('//span[@class="price"]' ,fucntion(result){
    thetext=result.value();
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned the `Selenium` bindings you are using so I will construct an Answer through `Java` bindings. Here we will use a customized `xpath` to locate the node with text `56,90 €` with out the `*` as follows:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='special-price']/span[contains(@class,'price') and not(@class='steuerstern')]"));
```